# Ant keeping Stack Exchange

Tags: feature-request

There should probably be an Ant keeping Stack Exchange, as we would probably get more traffic, because there are many Ant keeping forums out there, but they all seem to be outdated, while Stack Exchange stays alive. I'm sure there are a lot of ant keepers out there who could be helped by other ant keepers and ant experts, and the Stack Exchange community in general.

If this request is denied, could anyone please link me to a good Ant keeping forum where I could post my questions?

Comment: Proposals for new sites should be posted on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com). Meanwhile, let's see if this isn't on-topic on [Pets.SE].

Comment: Nope not on pets, not a very active community on those who figured out where to post ant questions over on  biology

Comment: Ya lol TBH that is the root of this question

Comment: http://forum.antscanada.com/ appears to be active, and the first Google result.

Comment: I didnt notice that it was active. It seems hard to navigate though. Stack exchange is much easier IMO

Comment: Assuming this is a problem you're currently facing (your posted example question) I don't see why you don't post on Pets.SE and see how it goes. Your proposal will need to get 200 people interested (which seems a bit unlikely to me) and even if it is wildly popular it'll be a few weeks before the site is actually created.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to create a new site, you can propose one on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com).

However, you should check if your topic isn't already covered by an existing Stack Exchange site.

If you are interested in keeping ants, the questions can fit under the `[insects]` tag on [Pets Stack Exchange](https://pets.stackexchange.com) .

If you are interested in ants as a species, looking at the scientific aspects, then [Biology Stack Exchange](https://biology.stackexchange.com) is the place.

You observed that there aren't many questions about ants on Pets Stack Exchange; the subject apparently is a bit of a niche. That, however, means it will be hard to get enough traction on Area 51 to get "Ants Stack Exchange" off the ground.

Your best bet, IMO, is to ask your questions on Pets Stack Exchange. Make sure they're well researched and follow the guidelines for that site, and hope another enthusiast picks them up. Small subjects don't make active Stack Exchange sites, but can have very active tags within a bigger site. The challenge is to ask some questions that will make the tag popular - which, although hard, is easier than going through the entire Area 51 site creation process.

Comment: Could I link to this post for the "  
Please describe or link to the community where you will be publicizing this proposal:" section if I were to try the Area 51 thing?

Comment: @PythonDude29 I don't know, I haven't proposed a site in a while.

Comment: Ill try (Jeez I and two ls look weird together)

Comment: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/118934/ant-keeping?referrer=7b-zOkGcf41oqEmN_KSxtw2

Comment: Well, good luck, @PythonDude29 ! Consider adding a few interesting example questions. (Don't ask me, I'm not knowledgeable enough.) Also, you _will_ be asked how your site differs from the "insects" tag on Pets.SE - so be prepared to answer that. Just saying "it's not active there" won't cover it, you'll have to show that your proposed site offers something that Pets SE does not. Anyway, good luck!

Comment: I dont need to ask you I have two Camponotus queens and I have had problems with them, I added one already and I have other ideas, Ive also done some research on ants becuase i want my queens tgo have big healthy colonies

Comment: @PythonDude29 That first sample question looks like a good one!

Comment: Thanks I have more ideas. They need improvment, though.

Comment: wow this was removed for inactivity? Was only up 2 days